# Launching the previous activity

Tags: android

Let's say that from the activity A, the activity B is launched and from B is launched C. Is it OK to start the activity A from C, by pressing a button, instead of pressing the BACK button twice, or is it a memory leak practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to do that:

`Activity A:

```
public static final int ID = X  
      // ....  
     startActivityForResult(intentToB,ID)  
     // ....  

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ID){
        switch (resultCode){
        case RESULT_OK:
            //...
            break;
        case RESULT_RETURN:
            // ...
        default:
                            //...
        }
    }
}
```

`

`  Activity B:

```
public static final int ID = Y  
      // ....  
     startActivityForResult(intentToC,ID)  
     // ....  

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ID){
        switch (resultCode){
        case RESULT_OK:
            //...
            break;
        case RESULT_RETURN:
            setResult(RESULT_RETURN);
                            ActivityB.this.finish();
        default:
                            //...
        }
    }
}
```

`

`Activity C:

     //inside of button onclick listener

    setResult(RESULT_VOLVER);

    ActivityC.this.finish();`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but could you be more specific?

Comment: in a Activity u can start other activity waiting for resulte with `startActivityForResult(intent, IDofActivityA)`
and catch the responses of activity B with the method `onActivityResult` If you create a response like RESULT_RETURN and controle it with onActivityResult you can create a "way" from Activity C to Activity A:

Activity A call Activity B call Activity C ---> setResult(RETURN).  Activity B catch --> setResult(return) and Activity A catch . You pass across all activity you want without press return button.

Sorry for my english. I cant be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I understand your idea. It seems from HomeActivity, you enter Activity A, and next to Activity B, and so one. Imaging each Acitivy (A, B,...), there is an HOME button for quickly return to HOME when press this button.

Here is the source code:

```
public void btn_home_click(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: If you call finish, then you  won't be able to go back to the previous activity. If you don't, new "same" activities will be launched.